# What is the proof-theoretic ordinal of $ \mathsf{PA}+\mathsf{TI}(\prec_{\varepsilon_0})$?

Tags: proof-theory, ordinal-analysis

$ \mathsf{TI}(\prec_{\varepsilon_0}) $ is transfinite induction on $\varepsilon_0$ ordinal notation by Cantor normal form.
I think that proof-theoretic ordinal of $\mathsf{PA}+\mathsf{TI}(\prec_{\varepsilon_0})$ is more than $\varepsilon_0$, but I don't understand how to how to calculate it.

Comment: This question is posted a month ago, so I wonder you have found an answer.